# What error is udivmodsi4?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I suddenly came across this error while compiling for iOS

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "___udivmodsi4"
```

What is this error and how can I get rid of it? I am on Xcode 4.4.

Comment: Is your compiler set to Apple LLVM or the LLVM GCC ?

Comment: The linker says that non of the libraries and objects you are linking contains the symbol named `udivmodsi4` for the platform based a ARM7 CPU. Does something like this also occur when building for the simulator (i386)?

Comment: @JohnSmith well then obviously one of the libraries or objects you are using has not been compiled to be used with ARM7. Try a clean build first. If that does not help, try to identify all subprojects and libraries used within your project - then rebuild all of those.

Comment: @Till: I've done so much cleaning the drive must be shiny by now. All I know to have changed since it last worked was the updating of MacOS to 10.8.2.

Comment: I saw this error several times when I was compiling static lib with LLVM GCC, another one with LLVM, ... I mean, is everything used in your project, subprojects, libs, ... compiled/linked/... with the same toolchain? If not, try to clean it, change config to use same toolchain and try again. But it was long time ago ...

Comment: It seems rather weird that this symbol (function) is actually missing as that seems to be a function deep down within the math lib of iOS itself. I would put my money on entirely screwed project linkage settings. Would you be able to create a new project that contains only a subset of your stuff to replicate the problem?

Comment: @Till: It's a rather massive project spanning 6 libraries over perhaps 2K files. The problem just started yesterday.

Comment: @JohnSmith narf, you might have to bite the bullet and rebuild all libs. Make sure their project settings are valid and compatible with the latest Xcode. Sorry dude!

Comment: @Till: bit the bullet. Nasty. Took forever to compile... But works now.

Comment: @JohnSmith awesome - glad that bugger got nailed.