# Why do I get this error when compiling a LiveCode iOS external for device but it compiles fine for the simulator?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, dropbox, livecode

Here's the error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "___udivmodsi4", referenced from:
      _sqlite3BitvecSet in libmergDropboxSync.a(sqlite3.o)
      _sqlite3BitvecClear in libmergDropboxSync.a(sqlite3.o)
      _sqlite3BitvecTest in libmergDropboxSync.a(sqlite3.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
lipo: can't open input file: /var/folders/np/1scdfrdd7kx64bbykn22wj200000gn/T//ccvBM79H.out (No such file or directory)
error: linking step of external dylib build failed, probably due to missing framework or library references - check the contents of the mergDropboxSync.ios file
Command /bin/sh emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure
```

When I build for the simulator it builds fine. My library is compiling fine. It's only at the linking stage for the dylib that is documented in lclink.sh as only for a dependency check for device builds that there's an issue:

```
# Build the 'dylib' form of the external - this is used by simulator builds, and as
# a dependency check for device builds.
"$PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_BIN_DIR/g++" -dynamiclib $ARCHS -isysroot "$SDKROOT" -o "$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/$PRODUCT_NAME.dylib" "$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/$EXECUTABLE_NAME" $SYMBOL_ARGS $SYMBOLS $DEPS
if [ $? != 0 ]; then
    echo "error: linking step of external dylib build failed, probably due to missing framework or library references - check the contents of the $PRODUCT_NAME.ios file"
    exit $?
fi
```

I tried skipping this step using the following:

```
if [ "$EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME" == "-iphonesimulator" ]; then
    # Build the 'dylib' form of the external - this is used by simulator builds, and as
    # a dependency check for device builds.
    "$PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_BIN_DIR/g++" -dynamiclib $ARCHS -isysroot "$SDKROOT" -o "$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/$PRODUCT_NAME.dylib" "$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/$EXECUTABLE_NAME" $SYMBOL_ARGS $SYMBOLS $DEPS
    if [ $? != 0 ]; then
        echo "error: linking step of external dylib build failed, probably due to missing framework or library references - check the contents of the $PRODUCT_NAME.ios file"
        exit $?
    fi
fi
```

This allowed the script to continue on and build the object files for static linking in the device builds. They built fine but then when I went to build the standalone the dependency check blocked it. Is there any workaround anyone can recommend?

Note that I use a slightly modified lclink.sh which adds weak linking support and optional framework inclusion depending on the SDK you're building against. It can be found here if that helps:
http://repo.goulding.ws/livecodeiossdk/src/b570507fe48274cc4c0f90102809194eafe5225d/lclink.sh?at=master

---

**EDIT**

Given that the error was clearly armv7 related I tried a build against armv7s and it builds fine. I'm coming to the conclusion that the the new dropbox sync sdk may have some armv7s only code. It appears to be sqlite related based on the error. Not sure what else to try at this stage...

---

**EDIT**

It appears to be a toolchain issue caused by the Dropbox sync api being compiled with Apple LLVM and LiveCode externals and device builds being compiled with Apple GCC.

Comment: I am not familiar with LiveCode, but the bug is probably in whatever toolchain was used to build `libmergDropboxSync.a`. See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12663424/what-error-is-udivmodsi4).

Comment: Thanks I've seen that question which doesn't seem to have any answer which worries me. I've tried setting the compiler for libmergDropboxSync.a to Apple LLVM and LLVM GCC in Xcode. Makes no difference... didn't seem to help the OP on that question either.

Comment: Perhaps a clean build using a different version of Xcode?

Comment: @tc I've tried clean... will try Xcode 4.5 to see if it builds.

Comment: @runrevmark sent me some info: "It sounds like that div symbol is used when the compiler is Apple LLVM 3.0 - it is likely this is what the dropbox sdk lib is built with. The engine and externals are all set to build with Apple GCC 4.2 which means when linked it will be including the gcc low-level c support lib, and not the clang low-level c support lib." So it looks like this IS a toolchain issue but I may not be able to resolve it because I'm the man in the middle between two SDKs requiring two different toolchains... Why do Dropbox have a MIT framework and not provide source???

Comment: So when you said "I've tried setting the compiler for libmergDropboxSync.a to Apple LLVM and LLVM GCC" you didn't actually mean you could change its compiler?

Comment: @tc yes I changed the compiler for libmergDropboxSync.a (which didn't make any difference) because for LiveCode externals there's a shell script after the build that compiles a dylib for simulator and object file for device. That's where it's choking because it uses g++. I changed it to clang and it compiled fine but then the whole thing is compiled again when the external is linked to the LiveCode engine which again uses g++...

Comment: same issue with Xcode 4.5 which is not surprising because the issue isn't with Xcode's build...

Comment: Oh. Oh dear. Perhaps you could symlink g++ to run Clang instead? (Ewwww!)

Comment: Ha! I was just about to suggest the same, but with the same queasy feeling <g>.

Comment: It's not an ideal solution obviously... and would certainly take the fun out of sharing the external...

Answer (score 0):

Does this help any? I wrote this up when I was having a somewhat similar problem.

[runrev lesson on linking to a dylib library](http://lessons.runrev.com/s/lessons/m/4071/l/15029-linking-an-osx-external-bundle-with-a-dylib-library)

Comment: unfortunately not so simple